# Enum keyword use and the generation of .class behind the enum keyword

Tags: java

in this question i m confused how  all this .class is generated  classes are `A$Enum$1,A$Enum$2,A$Enum,A$Enum,A` plz expalin the concept behind it, i opened the .class file in which i dont understand the `A$Enum$2,A$Enum$1`    class code plz expalin me concept what that`.string` means

```
class A
{
    enum Enum
    {
       Q1,Q2,Q3{

       },
       Q4 {

       },
       Q5;
    }
    enum Enum1
    {}
}
```

A$Enum$1.class code

```
class .String extends .String
{

    .String(String s, int i)
    {
        super(s, i, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A total of 6 classes are created.

```
A$Enum$1 //Inner class created for Q3  
A$Enum$2 //Inner class created for Q4 
A$Enum    //Enum, the enum defined within A
A$Enum1   //Enum1, the enum defined within A
A$1      //Not sure
A        //Class A
```

Here is the decompiled code for `A$Enum$1`

```
Compiled from "A.java"
final class A$Enum$1 extends A$Enum{
    A$Enum$1(java.lang.String, int);
}
```

Disassembled code for the same.

```
   33:  invokespecial   #14; //Method A$Enum$1."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V  
   36:  putstatic       #15; //Field Q3:LA$Enum;  
   39:  new     #16; //class A$Enum$2
```